# Export option is not available for the Customer Voice project

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, dataverse, common-data-service, ms-forms

I have created a Customer Voice project but the Export option is not available.

Providing the image reference got from an article.
[image]

Can anyone help me why the option is not available for me and what is the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't export a project/survey.

If what you need is to promote your project/survey between environments use the copy and update functions. A dialog will prompt allowing you to choose the new environment where you are copying/updating the project/survey into.

For reference: [Manage Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-voice/manage-projects)